# expo - Error: Cannot find module 'expo/config'

Tags: reactjs, expo

I started a new project in expo for this I used the following command:

`npx create-expo-app --template`

when I try to run it with:

`npx expo start --web`

i get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'expo/config'
```

I have downgraded expo-cli to 6.3.2, this fixed it but I would like to work on the latest version of expo.